# Nested transactions in Entity Framework Core

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core, transactions, entity-framework-core

With `System.Transaction` you can nest `TransactionScope`'s eg:

```
using (var tran1 = new TransactionScope())
{
    // modify context

    using (var tran2 = new TransactionScope())
    {
        // modify context
        tran2.Complete();
    }

    tran1.Complete();
}
```

How can I simulate this behavior in Entity Framework Core 2.1 with `DbContext.Database.BeginTransaction()`?

Comment: Frankly speaking, your requirement is not clear. Please mention it clearly what you are expecting and why are you expecting this.

Comment: if `tran2` failed, what would `tran1` do?